# Junit for KafkaProducer from kafka-clients in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, junit

We are using org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer from `kafka-clients-1.0.0` for producing messages to broker.

Now, we need to write junit test case for this producer to send messages to mock kafka cluster

org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.MockProducer is there, but unable to use since both (KafkaProducer and MockProducer are impl of Producer)

**Note**: We need to spin up mock Kafka broker to execute junit test case.

**Note2**: We need to initialize KakfaProducer with mock brokers and send messages to queue

Comment: `kafka-clients-0.0.1` doesn't exist. Please clarify what exactly your error is. MockProducer or TopologyTestDriver are exactly what you want

Comment: Sorry it's `kafka-clients-1.0.0`. I don't have error yet. I'm still figuring  out how to write junit test case for org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer

Comment: The Kafka source code has unit tests of its own. Perhaps you should start there?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Could you please share some docs of initializing KafkaProducer with mock broker and send messages. I couldn;t find. Just FYI We are not using Spring.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/MockProducerTest.java

Comment: You don't need to use Spring to simply use an embedded or mock broker. For example https://github.com/salesforce/kafka-junit/tree/master/kafka-junit5#kafkatestutils